# Popularity of tank beer

Tags: storage, draught, restaurants

In Czech Republic pubs with tank beer are pretty common and popular. There in many pubs and restaurants the beer is not stored in mobile casks or kegs but in much larger stationary tanks.

[image]

Here is interesting [article about tank beer in Prague](http://www.expats.cz/prague/article/czech-food-drink/tank-beer-in-prague/).

It seems that in other countries tank beer is not popular so much. For example I have found some [references from United Kingdom](http://tankbeer.co.uk/) but there the tank beer seems to be used mainly on sport stadiums and other large facilities.

How is tank beer popular in other countries? Is not tank beer in pubs and restaurants only a Czech phenomenon?

Comment: I've actually only seen this at large events such as festivals.

Answer (score 4):

According to the article you linked to, the specific draw of tank beer is that it's unpasteurized.  This does also exist (albeit not served from tanks) in the form of Real Ale, or Cask Ale in Britain.  Historically, this was not only popular, but the *primary* distribution mechanism for beer in Britain a hundred years ago.  However, its popularity has diminished over time because it's harder to transport and doesn't last as long as pasteurized beer, making it more expensive which necessarily reduces the size of the market that can and will pay for it.

Tanked beer is something that you see in brewpubs in the United States, where transportation isn't an issue (since it's being brewed on-site) but real ale is definitely on the decline in the U.K. and possibly only survives due to CAMRA, the British Beer Preservation Society's Campaign for Real Ale.

Answer (score 2):

Tank beer does seem to be mainly a Czech thing, although there are some pubs in England that use tanks too. In terms of why it might not be as popular in other countries, there seem to be some downsides: you would need to clean the tanks about once a week, also if you are dealing with unpasteurized beer it must be consumed in a shorter time period which may lead to possible waste of product.

Link to a article of a pub in England with tank beer [here](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/features/how-very-refreshing-tank-beer-is-so-fresh-its-like-drinking-straight-from-the-brewery-8560688.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. In fact in Czech Republic the beer is inside a disposable polypropylene sack in the tank to make the cleaning easier and avoid contact with pushing gas (normally air). --- The link in your answer is probably wrong. It points to http://diy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Oh,very interesting. - sorry for the bad link, (not used to formatting yet) link should work now. Cheers